# How i can redirect from "www.mywebsite.com////" to "www.mywebsite.com"?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

Now I'm using:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

for redirect from "www.mywebsite.com/**page/**" or "www.mywebsite.com/**page////**" to "www.mywebsite.com/**page**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]

# remove multiple slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [R=302,L,NE]
```